# can I run dual monitors on a asus P8H67-M LE

Tags: multiple-monitors, motherboard

I'm contemplating replacing my old system with a home-brewed system based on an ASUS P8H67-M LE Motherboard.

Can I run dual monitors on it (one on the DVI port, one on the HDMI port), or do I have to get a separate video card for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the [specifications](http://ca.asus.com/en/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8H67M_LE/#specifications). I must have scanned right over it the first time I looked.

```
Multi-VGA Output Support: HDMI, DVI-D and D-SUB Ports
```